# How to modify a global variable from a mounted function? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js and I couldn't find an answer online. I have a function in 'mounted:' and I need it to update a global variable.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <div id="MovieContent">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <div class="movie-details-container">
            <h3 class="movie-title">{{movieTitle}}</h3>
            <IMG class="movie-poster" :src="moviePosterURL" alt=""/>
            <p class="movie-description">{{movieDescription}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import { MdField } from 'vue-material/dist/components'

    Vue.use(MdField);

    const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=API_KEY&';
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const POSTER_API_URL = 'http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=API_KEY&';

    const movieName = null;
    const moviePoster = null;
    const moviePlot = null;

    export default {
        data: () => ({
            movieTitle: movieName,
            moviePosterURL: moviePoster,
            movieDescription: moviePlot
        }),
        methods: {

        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.$root.$on('SEND_SEARCH_INPUT', (text) => {
                async function fetchMovie(text) {
                    try {
                        const movieDetails = await fetch(API_URL + `t=${text}`);
                        const myJSON = await movieDetails.json();

                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log(myJSON['Title']);
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log(myJSON['Year']);
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log(myJSON['Poster']);
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log(myJSON['Plot']);
                    } catch (error) {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                }

                fetchMovie(text)

            })
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I want 'fetchMovie(text)' to update -movieName -moviePoster -moviePlot.

I have been reading the docs for a while now but nothing helps in this. Maybe I'm not catching the idea of how to pass data from functions, components and else.

Any advice? thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried movieName = something? etc

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Your statement is in a try catch. Does anything get logged to the console?

Comment: It's not assigning the new value to the variable. The console logs the API request as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
const movie = //your value
```

**const** keyword in JavaScript is used to define scope level constants. const variable cannot be reassigned, it must be assigned while initialisation.

```
const a;
a = 10;
```

This is absurd. So instead of **const** use **let**

```
let movie =//your value
```

It  will declare a scope level variable. You can read more on the topics online. As far as vue is concerned.

```
 <script>
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import { MdField } from 'vue-material/dist/components' Vue.use(MdField); 
 const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=API_KEY&'; // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
   const POSTER_API_URL = 'http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=API_KEY&'; 

 let movieName = null; 
 let moviePoster = null; 
 let moviePlot = null; 
 export default { 
 data: () => ({ movieTitle: movieName, moviePosterURL: moviePoster, movieDescription: moviePlot }), 
 methods: { },
 mounted: function () {
      movieName = this.movieName;
      moviePoster = this.moviePoster;
      MoviePlot = this.moviePlot;
  } 
} 
</script>
```

Use this context inside the  object  to reference all the thing which is associated with vue.

Comment: I've been writing vue for more the a year now. This is how I do it. Are you are accessing this in some other file you won't be able to acess it. I am assuming that is the thing you are trying and unable to do it. Create a file where are you defining your variables and impot it wherever you need it. Feel free to correct me if that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue, you can directly modify whatever is declared in the data of your component. It's a good practice to put your variables in one containing object. It's clean, and, mostly, Vue can't track changes if you overwrite the root of an object tree it's watching, so...

```
let vueStore = {
    movieName:null,
    moviePoster:null,
    moviePlot:null,
}
export default { 
data(){ return {vueStore: vueStore} }, 
methods: { },
mounted: function () {
    this.vueStore.movieName = this.movieName;
    this.vueStore.moviePoster = this.moviePoster;
    this.vueStore.MoviePlot = this.moviePlot;
} 
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Are there errors at the console? Have you got vue devtools open? Arrow functions are often a bad idea in Vue components. I've rewritten the answer without the arrow function. Try that?